# Patent Term Adjustment

Tags: uspto, term

I got a notification from uspto that

> The Patent Term Adjustment is 58 days

I would like to know what is PTA and how is it calculated ?

Answer (score 1):

A granted US patent usually lasts 20 years from the application date (assuming all the renewal fees are paid). So, if you applied for the patent on 1 July 2001, and it was granted, it would last until 1 July 2021.

If the USPTO takes too long to review the application, you will be granted an extension of this 20 year period (see [MPEP § 2730](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2730.html) for details). This extension is called the "patent term extension".

Thus, in the above example, if the patent term extension is 18 days, the actual expiry date would be 19 July 2021.